# WordPress: Delete all post with English language in title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog site that auto blog, and now I want to delete all posts that have English language in title.

For example:-

I have title like (UGG Ascot 5775 Noir Homme Super Qualité) its English title, I need to delete all this title, Because i need to show Arabic title only

There are too many posts (400+) to do it manually.

Are there any plugin that may help to auto delete a blog post?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably tell everyone what you've already tried and post an example. Include some context, such as code to fetch each post and attempt to detect the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query on mysql command prompt or phpmyadmin (or each tool that you use):

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '([A-Za-z])';
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing that may help is that I think you don't want to detect the language (That's French, not English) as much as the *Alphabet* and *Character Set*. I don't know a lot about Arabic, but is it Sanskrit characters you want to keep? Perhaps you could use UTF-8, find the characters that are present in Arabic writing, and loop through each post, deleting any post that *does not* have at least one Sanskrit character in the title. For example, here's documentation for an [Arabic UTF-8 codepage](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&utf8=string-literal). You can then check for the presence of these UTF-8 characters in the title string.

Actually detecting the *language*, rather than the *alphabet* will be a tricky task that will likely require some Machine Learning.